# rbenv sets wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install and use ruby 2.4.0, using rbenv.

I installed both 2.3.0 and 2.4.0-dev versions.

When checking in `~/.rbenv/version` , I see both versions.

When typing `which ruby`, I get `/home/wolf/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

`ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-03-14 trunk 57970) [x86_64-linux]`

Obsiously, when I try to start a Rails app, which Gemfile specifies ruby 2.4.0, I get the `Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0` error.

I also set `rbenv -global 2.4.0-dev`

Did I miss something ? Is there anyting to add to my ~PATH beside `~/.rbenv/shims` ?

Comment: Does running `rbenv local 2.4.0` in the project root help?

Comment: Look at this [github rbenv issue 1045](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1045#issuecomment-272817120) and then tell me what you think.